# 2D Polygon Collider not causing collisions with a 2d polygon collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am in the middle of working on a game, and I just started. I added in the map as a png and have been adding in colliders around the areas that I want to be impassable (it is a 2D platformer). I have an enemy already designed and added a 2DRigidBody component to it as it moves around, and started to use 2DBoxColliders as the colliders for the level, and my script that I have written:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sexapus : MonoBehaviour {

public static int Velocity = 42;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public Vector2 dir;
public Animator anim;

void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    dir = new Vector2(1, 0);
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    rb.velocity = dir * Velocity;
    anim.SetFloat ("Direction", dir.x);
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) {
    dir = dir * -1;
}

//CHECK TASKS
}
```

Meant that the enemy would hit the side of a wall and then rotate and start going the other way. I realised with the size of my map that using multiple 2DBoxColliders (and when I say multiple I mean I would probably have to use over a hundred) was a very bad way of doing it. I have now started to use a 2DpolygonCollider for the map as well, but now the enemy doesn't collide with the sides of the wall and turn around, it just stays facing the same direction but doesn't move. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same collider for the floor and the walls... So when you collide with the wall, and are already touching the floor, the OnCollisionEnter will not happen.

So, you do get the collision, hence the object cant move past the wall, BUT it's not a new collision!

Solution: Use a collider to the floor, and a different one to the walls, Edge colliders are good for this.